# Python for loop in elif statement not executing

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement

I've worked with python a lot over the last 3 years during university and I have never encountered an issue as strange as this before. Some background this program is being used for my final year assignment and what I'm finding strange is that the code functions perfectly normal in one file but in my assignment file it doesn't. The goal of the code is to receive an input string and then loop though it using the replace functions method. It the replaces all instances of '*' with the table name X and all instances of '!' with column names in that table X. I've located the issue arising from the replace_characters() function. This function is supposed to receive an input str and then loop through it until it finds either an '!' or an '*'. If I input just a '_' in the input str it works perfectly, however as soon as I input an '!', it then hits the elif statement prints "tests" and then doesn't proceed with the for loop. I find this peculiar as as I mentioned earlier the code functions completely normally in my original file but not the assignment file.

```
`from tkinter import *
import random
import sqlite3
import array
import itertools

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1000x1000")
root.title(" Question Generation ")
arrtables=[]
arrcolumns=[]
exclamation_replacements=[]
def replace_characters(input_str, index, current_str, combinations, used_exclamation):
 # If we've processed the entire string, add the current_str to combinations
 if index == len(input_str):
     print("test")
     combinations.append(current_str)
     return
 
 # If the current character is '_', replace it with each replacement
 if input_str[index] == '_':
     print("test2")
     #for replacement in underscore_replacements:
     replacement=underscore_replacements[0]
     replace_characters(input_str, index+1 , current_str + replacement, combinations, used_exclamation)
 # If the current character is '!', replace it with unused replacements
 elif input_str[index] == '!':
     print("tests")
     for replacement in exclamation_replacements:
         if replacement not in used_exclamation:
             print("test3")
             used_exclamation.add(replacement)  # Mark the replacement as used
             replace_characters(input_str, index + 1, current_str + replacement, combinations, used_exclamation)
             used_exclamation.remove(replacement)  # Unmark the replacement when backtracking
 # If it's any other character, keep it as is
 else:
     print("test4")
     replace_characters(input_str, index + 1, current_str + input_str[index], combinations, used_exclamation)

def get_tables():
 try:
     # Making a connection between sqlite3
     # database and Python Program
     sqliteConnection = sqlite3.connect('classicModels2022.db')
     # If sqlite3 makes a connection with python
     # program then it will print "Connected to SQLite"
     # Otherwise it will show errors
     #print("Connected to SQLite")

     # Getting all tables from sqlite_master
     sql_query = """SELECT name FROM sqlite_master
     WHERE type='table';"""

     # Creating cursor object using connection object
     cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor()
  
     # executing our sql query
     cursor.execute(sql_query)
     #print("List of tables\n")
  
     # printing all tables list
     tabs=cursor.fetchall()
     #arrtables=[tabs.__sizeof__]
     for i in tabs:
         i=str(i)
         i=i[:-3]
         i=i[2:]
         arrtables.append(i)
        # print(i)

 except sqlite3.Error as error:
     print("Failed to execute the above query", error)
  
 finally:
     # Inside Finally Block, If connection is
     # open, we need to close it
     if sqliteConnection:
         # using close() method, we will close
         # the connection
         sqliteConnection.close()
      
      # After closing connection object, we
      # will print "the sqlite connection is
      # closed"
        # print("the sqlite connection is closed")

def get_cols(tablename):
 conn = sqlite3.connect('classicModels2022.db')
 # Creating a cursor object using the cursor() method
 cursor = conn.cursor()
  
 # Display columns
 #print('\nColumns in EMPLOYEE table:')
 
 data=cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM "+tablename)
 for column in data.description:
     #print(column[0])
     #arrcolumns*=0
     arrcolumns.append(column[0])
 
 conn.close()
# Define arrays for replacement strings


l = Label(text = "Assignment Question Creation")
q=Label(text = "Input the question, where '!' denotes the column name and '_' denotes the table name:")
questiontxt = Text(root, height = 2,
             width = 75,
             bg = "light yellow")
a=Label(text="Input the SQL answer, where '!' denotes the column name and '_' denotes the table name:")
answertxt = Text(root, height = 2,
             width = 75,
             bg = "light yellow")

Output = Text(root, height = 15,
           width = 250,
           bg = "light cyan")

Display = Button(root, height = 2,
              width = 20,
              text ="Generate",
              command = lambda:Take_input())
btnExit=Button(root, height=2, width=20, text="Create and Exit", command=lambda:Add_Lists())
btnDelete=Button(root, height=2, width=20, text="Delete Questions", command=lambda:delete_list())
ldelete=Label(text="Enter a comma separated list to delete any generated combinations:")
lsave=Label(text="Press 'Create and Exit' to add the questions to the database and exit.")
cList = Text(root, height = 2,
           width = 75,
           bg = "light cyan")

# Initialize an empty list to store combinations


# Initialize a set to keep track of used exclamation replacements
combo1=[]
combinations=[]
underscore_replacements=[]



def Take_input():
 get_tables()
 print(arrcolumns)
 user_input = questiontxt.get("1.0", "end-1c")
 answer_input=answertxt.get("1.0","end-1c")
 #combo1=[]    
 print(arrtables)    
 # Initialize an empty list to store combinations
 #combinations = []
 # Initialize a set to keep track of used exclamation replacements
 used_exclamation = set()
 i=-1
 for y in arrtables:
     #print(y)
     i+=1
     del arrcolumns[:]
     del underscore_replacements[:]
     get_cols(y)
     underscore_replacements.append(arrtables[i])
     global exclamation_replacements
     exclamation_replacements=arrcolumns
     replace_characters(user_input, 0, "", combinations, used_exclamation)
     replace_characters(answer_input,0, "", combo1, used_exclamation)
     #Output.insert(END, combinations)
     #sOut=""
     print("Hello")
     print(combinations)
     print(combo1)
 for i in range(0,len(combinations), 1):
         Output.insert(END,f"Combination {i}: Question: {combinations[i]} Answer: {combo1[i]} \n")
         print(f"Combination {i}: Question: {combinations[i]} Answer: {combo1[i]}")
     
     
 #Output.insert(END,sOut)

def delete_list():
 user_input = cList.get("1.0","end-1c")
 # Split the input string into a list of integers
 input_list = [int(x.strip()) for x in user_input.split(',')]
 # Create an array (list) with some initial values
 #original_array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
 input_list.sort(reverse=True)
 #original_array=combinations
 # Delete elements from the original array at specified positions
 for position in input_list:
     if 0 <= position < len(combinations):
         #del original_array[position]
         del combinations[position]
         del combo1[position]
 # Print the modified array
 #print("Modified Array:", original_array)
 Output.delete("1.0","end-1c")
 for i in range(0,len(combinations), 1):
     Output.insert(END,f"Combination {i}: Question: {combinations[i]} Answer: {combo1[i]} \n")


l.pack()
q.pack()
questiontxt.pack()
a.pack()
answertxt.pack()
Display.pack()
Output.pack()
ldelete.pack()
cList.pack()
lsave.pack()
btnDelete.pack()
btnExit.pack()
mainloop()
`
The above code functions normally.
```

```
`class Auto_Generation:
    def main_screen():        
        root = Tk()
        root.geometry("1000x1000")
        root.title(" Question Generation ")
        arrtables=[]
        arrcolumns=[]
        exclamation_replacements=[]        
        underscore_replacements=[]
        def replace_characters(input_str, index, current_str, combinations, used_exclamation):
            # If we've processed the entire string, add the current_str to combinations
            print(index)
            print(input_str)
            #print(input_str[index])
            #print(len(input_str))
            if index==len(input_str):
                print("test1")
                combinations.append(current_str)
                return
            
            #
            if input_str[index]=='_':
                print("test2")
                for replacement in underscore_replacements:
                    replace_characters(input_str,index+1,current_str+replacement,combinations,used_exclamation)
            elif input_str[index]=='!':
                print("tests")
                for replacement in exclamation_replacements:
                    if replacement not in used_exclamation:
                        print("test3")
                        used_exclamation.add(replacement)
                        replace_characters(input_str,index+1,current_str+replacement,combinations,used_exclamation)
                        used_exclamation.remove(replacement)
                        
            else:
                print("test4")
                replace_characters(input_str,index+1,current_str+input_str[index],combinations,used_exclamation)
            
              
            '''if index == len(input_str):
                    print("cunt")
                    combinations.append(current_str)
                    return
            # If the current character is '_', replace it with each replacement
            if input_str[index] == '_':
                    print("cunt2")
                    #for replacement in underscore_replacements:
                    replacement=underscore_replacements[0]
                    replace_characters(input_str, index+1 , current_str + replacement, combinations, used_exclamation)
                    # If the current character is '!', replace it with unused replacements
            elif input_str[index] == '!':
                    for replacement in exclamation_replacements:
                        if replacement not in used_exclamation:
                            print("cunt3")
                            used_exclamation.add(replacement)  # Mark the replacement as used
                            replace_characters(input_str, index + 1, current_str + replacement, combinations, used_exclamation)
                            used_exclamation.remove(replacement)  # Unmark the replacement when backtracking
            # If it's any other character, keep it as is
            else:
                    print("cunt4")
                    replace_characters(input_str, index + 1, current_str + input_str[index], combinations, used_exclamation)
'''
        '''def replace_characters(input_str, index, current_str, combinations, used_exclamation):
            # If we've processed the entire string, add the current_str to combinations
            
            
            if index == len(input_str):
                print("cunt")
                combinations.append(current_str)
                return
            # If the current character is '_', replace it with each replacement
            if input_str[index] == "_":
                print("cunt2")
                #for replacement in underscore_replacements:
                replacement=underscore_replacements[0]
                replace_characters(input_str, index+1 , current_str + replacement, combinations, used_exclamation)
                # If the current character is '!', replace it with unused replacements
            elif input_str[index] == "!":
                for replacement in exclamation_replacements:
                    if replacement not in used_exclamation:
                        print("cunt3")
                        used_exclamation.add(replacement)  # Mark the replacement as used
                        replace_characters(input_str, index + 1, current_str + replacement, combinations, used_exclamation)
                        used_exclamation.remove(replacement)  # Unmark the replacement when backtracking
            # If it's any other character, keep it as is
            else:
                print("cunt4")
                replace_characters(input_str, index + 1, current_str + input_str[index], combinations, used_exclamation)
'''
        def get_tables():
            try:
            # Making a connection between sqlite3
            # database and Python Program
                sqliteConnection = sqlite3.connect('classicModels2022.db')
            # If sqlite3 makes a connection with python
            # program then it will print "Connected to SQLite"
            # Otherwise it will show errors
            #print("Connected to SQLite")
            # Getting all tables from sqlite_master
                sql_query = """SELECT name FROM sqlite_master
                WHERE type='table';"""
            # Creating cursor object using connection object
                cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor()
            # executing our sql query
                cursor.execute(sql_query)
            #print("List of tables\n")
            # printing all tables list
                tabs=cursor.fetchall()
            #arrtables=[tabs.__sizeof__]
                for i in tabs:
                    i=str(i)
                    i=i[:-3]
                    i=i[2:]
                    arrtables.append(i)
                # print(i)
            except sqlite3.Error as error:
                print("Failed to execute the above query", error)
            finally:
            # Inside Finally Block, If connection is
            # open, we need to close it
                if sqliteConnection:
                # using close() method, we will close
                # the connection
                    sqliteConnection.close()
                # After closing connection object, we
                # will print "the sqlite connection is
                # closed"
                # print("the sqlite connection is closed")
        def get_cols(tablename):
            conn = sqlite3.connect('classicModels2022.db')
        # Creating a cursor object using the cursor() method
            cursor = conn.cursor()
        # Display columns
        #print('\nColumns in EMPLOYEE table:')
            data=cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM "+tablename)
            for column in data.description:
            #print(column[0])
            #arrcolumns*=0
                arrcolumns.append(column[0])
            conn.close()
    
# Define arrays for replacement strings


        l = Label(text = "Assignment Question Creation")
        q=Label(text = "Input the question, where '!' denotes the column name and '_' denotes the table name:")
        questiontxt = Text(root, height = 2,width = 75, bg = "light yellow")
        a=Label(text="Input the SQL answer, where '!' denotes the column name and '_' denotes the table name:")
        answertxt = Text(root, height = 2,width = 75,bg = "light yellow")
        Output = Text(root, height = 15,width = 250,bg = "light cyan")

        Display = Button(root, height = 2,width = 20,text ="Generate",command = lambda:Take_input())
        btnExit=Button(root, height=2, width=20, text="Create and Exit", command=lambda:submit_questions())
        btnDelete=Button(root, height=2, width=20, text="Delete Questions", command=lambda:delete_list())
        ldelete=Label(text="Enter a comma separated list to delete any generated combinations:")
        lsave=Label(text="Press 'Create and Exit' to add the questions to the database and exit.")
        cList = Text(root, height = 2,width = 75,bg = "light cyan")
        spnBoxLevel = Spinbox(root, from_= 1, to=3)       

# Initialize an empty list to store combinations


# Initialize a set to keep track of used exclamation replacements
        #combo1=[]
        #combinations=[]
        #underscore_replacements=[]
        combo1=[]
        combinations=[]

        def Take_input():
            get_tables()
            #print(arrcolumns)
            user_input = questiontxt.get("1.0", "end-1c")
            answer_input=answertxt.get("1.0","end-1c")
            #combo1=[]                
            print(arrtables)   
            # Initialize an empty list to store combinations
            #combinations = []
            # Initialize a set to keep track of used exclamation replacements
            used_exclamation = set()
            i=-1
            for y in arrtables:
                #print(y)
                i+=1
                del arrcolumns[:]
                del underscore_replacements[:]
                get_cols(y)
                underscore_replacements.append(arrtables[i])
                global exclamation_replacements
                exclamation_replacements=arrcolumns
                replace_characters(user_input, 0, "", combinations, used_exclamation)
                replace_characters(answer_input,0, "", combo1, used_exclamation)
                #Output.insert(END, combinations)
                #sOut=""
                print("Hello")
                print(combinations)
                print(combo1)
            for i in range(0,len(combinations), 1):
                Output.insert(END,f"Combination {i}: Question: {combinations[i]} Answer: {combo1[i]} \n")
                print(f"Combination {i}: Question: {combinations[i]} Answer: {combo1[i]}")
        
        
    #Output.insert(END,sOut)

        def delete_list():
            user_input = cList.get("1.0","end-1c")
          # Split the input string into a list of integers
            input_list = [int(x.strip()) for x in user_input.split(',')]
         # Create an array (list) with some initial values
    #original_array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
            input_list.sort(reverse=True)
        #original_array=combinations
        # Delete elements from the original array at specified positions
            for position in input_list:
                if 0 <= position < len(combinations):
                #del original_array[position]
                    del combinations[position]
                    del combo1[position]
    # Print the modified array
    #print("Modified Array:", original_array)
            Output.delete("1.0","end-1c")
            for i in range(0,len(combinations), 1):
               Output.insert(END,f"Combination {i}: Question: {combinations[i]} Answer: {combo1[i]} \n")


        def submit_questions():
            id=Logic.addQuestions.getLastQuestion(int(spnBoxLevel.get()))
            print(id)
            x=(id[0])
            s=str(x)        
            s=s[1:-1]   
            y = [(b.strip()) for b in s.split(',')]
            iid=int(y[0])
            if (messagebox.askokcancel("Generate Questions","Are you sure you want to submit these combinations?")):                
                for i in range(0,len(combinations),1):
                    iid+=1
                    Logic.addQuestions.createQuestions(iid,int(spnBoxLevel.get()),combinations[i],combo1[i]) # add this new question to the database              
                    

                    # Change screens
                messagebox.showinfo('','Questions succesfully added!')
                root.destroy()
                LecturerHomeForm.main_screen()
            
            
            
        l.pack()
        q.pack()
        questiontxt.pack()
        a.pack()
        answertxt.pack()
        Display.pack()
        Output.pack()
        ldelete.pack()
        cList.pack()
        lsave.pack()
        spnBoxLevel.pack()
        btnDelete.pack()
        btnExit.pack()
        mainloop()`
```

This is the code that doesn't work. I've tried rewriting the function replace_characters and making sure everything is properly indented, nothing seems to change. Any help is greatly appreciated, I'm sure it's a simple thing I might be missing.

Comment: The only reason that it didn't go inside the loop is that `exclamation_replacements` was empty

Comment: For future questions please learn how to create a [mre]. With emphasis on the *minimal* part.

Comment: I understand that but what I don't get is that underscore_replacements was also initiated as an empty array and if I use an input string of just "_", then it works fine, but as soon as I introduce an input string of "! _" or any input string for that matter containing an "!", then it doesn't function normally.

Comment: Apologies "Some programmer dude", its my first time using stack overflow and I didn't know about that. I'll do that from now on.

Comment: I finally sorted it out, I took out that global exclamation_replacements code and the line afterwards saying exclamation_replacements=arrcolumn. I replaced it with a line outside of a method saying exclamation_replacements=arrcolumn